# C# Web Service Unit Tests

Tags: c#, testing, soap

I have the following Entity:

```
Amount

Currency -  String

Value -  decimal
```

I have also a wcf service that uses this entity and I want to make a unit test to this class.

My problem is that I want test invalid values to the Value in the entity and if I try to assign in in the c#

```
Amout m = new Amout{Currency = "EUR", Value = "aaaa"}
```

gave error.

How can I test this situation?

For example I can make the following request in soapUI:

```
<itc1:Amount>
  <itc2:Currency>EUR</itc2:Currency>
  <itc2:Value>aaaaaa</itc2:Value>
</itc1:Amount>
```

and I get error from the service.

I want to make the same with an unit test.

I hope you can help me.

Comment: It would really help if you could as the exact error message you get. Please see [ask]

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for something like this :

```
    [TestMethod()]
    [ExpectedException(typeof(KnownExceptionType))]
    public void Test()
    {
        //Do something that throws a KnownExceptionType 
    }
```